# How to make (neo)vim replace a selection with the clipboard?

Tags: vim, nvim

```
Let's say I have "some example" text
```

If I want to change the text inside quotes, and because I have `set clipboard=unnamed`¹ in my configuration, I have to `"qci"` then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. `"q` is a random register to not overwrite the system clipboard.

Any way to replicate this process with fewer keystrokes? Ideally I’d do the commands to define the area to replace (e.g. `i"`, `3W`) and one other key.

---

¹ Copy and paste to and from the system clipboard

Comment: "Doctor Doctor, it hurts every time I hit my head against the wall!" "Well stop hitting your head against the wall then". You set the option to use the system clipboard and then want to avoid it being used. Perhaps you should consider setting up a shortcut to turn on and off the default use of the system clipboard? Alternatively set up a more elaborate "system clipboard" so a semi-infinite number of clipboard entries can be saved at the same time.

Comment: @icarus What's the point of being snarky to strangers? If you cannot say anything productive on a Q&A site, consider taking a break from the internet. I sincerely wish you a positive and relaxed weekend, and that anything bothering you gets resolved in a peaceful way. As to your suggestions, I already use a clipboard manager and the other approach is going to take more keystrokes for something only required on occasion. I didn’t expect this to need to be spelled out in such detail, but that option is in my config because it’s what I want the overwhelming majority of the time.